# Dir refers twice to same file

Tags: vba, excel

I am using this code

```
 sFile = Dir(sFold & "*.xls*")

 Do While sFile <> "" MsgBox (sFile)

     ext = "." + Right$(sFile, Len(sFile) - InStrRev(sFile, ".")) 
     sFile = Replace(sFile, ext, "")

     Name sFold + sFile + ext As sFold + tbPrefiks4.Value + sFile +
     tbSufiks4.Value + ext

     sFile = Dir

 Loop
```

in order to rename all files in directory but it seems that in some cases Dir returns the file that has been changed in former iteration /it renames all files in directory and then goes back to renaming first one/. Is there any workaround for this problem ?

Example: i have 3 files 1.xlsx, 2.xlsx, 3.xlsx and would like to add A_ prefix and _W sufix to them, so it renames it to A_1_W.xlsx , A_2_W.xlsx and A_3_W.xlsx but then goes back to first one and changes it to A_A_1_W_W.xlsx and thats all. Whats weird is that without '_' it doesnt happen.

Comment: try to use 2 different cycles: 1st to accumulate list of filenames (like existed), 2nd to perform renaming of files according to the list.